# Use Bernouilli's Inequality to verify $\left(\frac{n(n+2)}{(n+1)^2}\right)^{n+1}\geq \frac{n}{n+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Bernouilli's Inequality states that, for $x\geq -1$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $(1+x)^n\geq 1+xn$.

The exercise gives the hint to apply Bernouilli's Inequality to the left hand side of the inequality we're trying to prove:
$$\left(\frac{n(n+2)}{(n+1)^2}\right)^{n+1}\geq \frac{n}{n+1}.$$

I've tried rewriting it as

$$\left(\frac{n(1+(n+1))}{(n+1)^2}\right)^{n+1}$$

so that the Bernouilli Inequality tells us it's greater or equal to

$$\frac{n^{n+1}(1+(n+1)^2)}{(n+1)^{2n+2}}.$$

At this point, I'm stuck. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that 
$$ \frac{n(n+2)}{(n+1)^2}=\frac{n^2+2n}{(n+1)^2}=1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$$
so by Bernoulli's inequality,
$$ \Big(1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\Big)^{n+1}\geq 1-\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{n}{n+1}$$